# how to local storage data in browser tin angular2

Tags: angular, token, hide

I'm using local storage to store some data of my website. I store each object that the site need. So on the client's browser, I want to hide the local storage data in browser in angular2

Here is the code:

```
login(login, form: NgForm) { 
    this.spinner = true;
    var body = "email=" + login.email + "&password=" + login.password;
    this._LoginService.login(body).subscribe(logindata => { 
    this.spinner = false;
    this.logindata = logindata;
    if (logindata && logindata.token) { 
        window.localStorage.accessToken = logindata.token;
        this._tokenService.setToken(logindata.token);
        window.localStorage.setItem('name', logindata.user_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot hide localstorage from browser's developer tools. You should always remember 'Do not trust the client side'

Comment: how to passs token total website using angular 2

Comment: are you asking how to store and retrieve data from localStorage ?

Comment: with out localstorage how to pass token one component to other component

Comment: u don't need localstorage to pass data from one component to another. see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: login(login, form: NgForm) {
    this.spinner=true;
    var body = "email=" + login.email + "&password=" + login.password ;
    this._LoginService.login(body)
      .subscribe(
      logindata => {
        this.spinner=false;
        this.logindata=logindata;
      if (logindata && logindata.token ) {
          window.localStorage.accessToken=logindata.token
          this._tokenService.setToken(logindata.token)
          window.localStorage.setItem('name', logindata.user_name);
          this.userlogin=false;
         ; 
      }

Comment: this my code.i want store stoken but that token will not be display in browser

Comment: pls add ur code in ur ques in proper format

Comment: login(login, form: NgForm) {
    this.spinner=true;
    var body = "email=" + login.email + "&password=" + login.password ;
    this._LoginService.login(body)
      .subscribe(
      logindata => {
        this.spinner=false;
        this.logindata=logindata;
      if (logindata && logindata.token ) {
          window.localStorage.accessToken=logindata.token
          this._tokenService.setToken(logindata.token)
          window.localStorage.setItem('name', logindata.user_name);
          
      }

Comment: is there any posibility using server side store token